# Why is the phase shift -c/b instead of -c

Tags: functions, trigonometry

In a function like $\sin(2x + 3)$ why is the phase shift $\frac{3}{2}$ units to the left instead of 3 units to the left

Comment: I would recommend you make tables of values for the functions $f(x) = \sin x$, $g(x) = \sin 2x$ and $h(x) = \sin (2x+3)$ with intervals of $0.1$ between values of $x$. Then see for what values of $x$ the functions return the same value. You'll find that $h(x) = g(x + 3/2)$, which explains the phase shift of $-3/2$. For example, $h(0.3) = g(1.8)$. So the point $(1.8, \sin 3.6)$ on the graph of $g$ corresponds to the point $(0.3, \sin 3.6)$ on the graph of $h$. That's $1.5$ units to the left of the corresponding point of the graph of $g$. Of course, you also must know how to...

Comment: ... find $h(x) = g(x + 3/2)$ algebraically.

Answer (score 2):

A phase shift for a function $f(x)$ by $c$ units is given by $f(x-c)$ (so if we're given a function $f(x)$ and we shift it to the right 5 units, we'll have $f(x-5)$).

For $\sin(2x+3)$, we no longer have a function of $x$ alone, but one of $2x$ (ignoring the shift for the moment). To "fix" this, factor out a power of 2 and you have $\sin\left(2\left(x+\dfrac{3}{2}\right)\right)$.

Comment: Why does it matter if x is being multiplied by a number or not? Why can't f(bx - c) also be shifted by -c units?

Answer (score 0):

One way of analyzing this function is by looking at it from the inside out. Suppose we break up the function into an infinite number of piece-wise component functions, and just study one of those components. Let's say, for example, that for $f(x) = \sin(2x+3)$ that I'm only interested in the interval $\bigg[\frac{5\pi-6}{4}, \frac{7\pi-6}{4}\bigg]$. Further suppose that $g(x)=\sin x$, but is only defined on $\bigg[\frac{5}{2}\pi,\frac{7}{2}\pi\bigg]$

We now take that component function and find its inverse.
$$f(x) = g(2x+3)\implies f(f^{-1}(x)) = g(2f^{-1}(x)+3)$$
$$\begin{array}{lll}
f(f^{-1}(x)) &=& g(2f^{-1}(x)+3)\\
x &=& g(2f^{-1}(x)+3)\\
g^{-1}(x) &=& 2f^{-1}(x)+3\\
g^{-1}(x) - 3 &=& 2f^{-1}(x)\\
\frac{g^{-1}(x) - 3}{2} &=& f^{-1}(x)\\
f^{-1}(x) &=& \frac{1}{2}g^{-1}(x) - \frac{3}{2}\\
\end{array}$$

It's clear from the last line that $f^{-1}$ is just $g^{-1}$ that has been compressed by a factor of $2$ vertically, and shifted downward by $\frac{3}{2}$. But, $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$, respectively are just $f$ and $g$ reflected across the $45^{\circ}$ line $y=x$. This means that a vertical compression of a factor of 2, and a downward shift of $-\frac{3}{2}$ for $g^{-1}$ translates into a horizontal compression and leftward shift of $\frac{3}{2}$ for $g$.

Graphically, the situation is as follows.
[image]

Finally, lets try unwinding our inside-out view, algebraically.
$$ f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{2}g^{-1}(x) - \frac{3}{2}=\frac{1}{2}g^{-1}(f(f^{-1}(x))) - \frac{3}{2}\implies x = \frac{1}{2}g^{-1}(f(x)) - \frac{3}{2}$$
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\\x = \frac{1}{2}g^{-1}(f(x)) - \frac{3}{2}
\\x+\frac{3}{2} = \frac{1}{2}g^{-1}(f(x))
\\2(x+\frac{3}{2}) = g^{-1}(f(x))
\\g(2(x+\frac{3}{2})) = g(g^{-1}(f(x)))=f(x)
\end{array}$$
As you can see the form $g(2(x+\frac{3}{2}))$ is more useful than $g(2x+3)$ in analyzing shifts and stretches, even though the two forms are equivalent.

Now, if we do this with every one-to-one component function, we find that all of these components are stretched (or compressed) and shifted horizontally in the same way, allowing us to claim that the horizonal shift of $\sin(bx+c)$ is, in fact, $-\frac{c}{b}$.