# Why is the phase shift of a sin or cosine wave $c/b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I recognize this is a copy of
[Why is the phase shift -c/b instead of -c](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953429/why-is-the-phase-shift-c-b-instead-of-c)
but I still don't understand. Plus that is five years old. Why is the phase shift of $y=\cos(2x-1)$ not one? Why is it $c/b$ or $1/2$?

Comment: One of the answers there is an explanation. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/953439/888233

Comment: Math hasn't changed *that* much in five years.

Comment: You are shifting $2x$ to the right by $1$, so dividing by $2$ gives us that we are shifting $x$ to the right by $\frac12$.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly helpful: Think of the phase shift as the value of $x$ that gives you an argument of $0$ in the sine or cosine function.  So for $y=\cos(2x-1)$, we set $2x-1 \stackrel{\rm set}= 0$. This gives $x=\frac12$, corresponding to putting $0$ into the cosine function, for a phase shift of $\frac12$.